# EntityFramework et join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I have a problem when I do a query via EF to retrieve the join data:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Customer cus INNER JOIN Adress addr ON addr.Id = cus.Adresse_Id WHERE cus.name = 'John' ";    
Model model = new Model();
List<Customer> cus = model.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(query).ToList();
```

I can only recover Client's properties

My two tables:

Customer :

[image]

Address :

[image]

I don't know how to retrieve the Adress's properties also.

---

I have a second problem: I have an object to create since a request EF and an object resulting directly from a webservice

I would like to compare the properties of each of both objects but I don't how see making otherwise with many conditions.

I try to explore quite a lot of tracks but unsuccessfully.

Thank's You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to retrieve the Adress's properties also.

You could make use of a join. According to your schema, you need something like the following:

```
var client = from customer in dbContext.Customer
             inner join address in dbContext.Address
             on customer.Address_Id equals address.Id
             where customer.Name = "John"
             select 
             {
                  CustomerId = customer.Id,
                  CustomerName = customer.Name,
                  Address = address.Addresse
                  AddressCodePostal = address.Code_postal
                  // ...
             };
```

where I have supposed that you have a `dbConetxt` class in order your application communicate with the database.

> Why your code doesn't do what you want it to do?

Here you after the execution of your query, you create a list of `Customer`

```
List<Customer> cus = model.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(query).ToList();
```

Certainly, the `Customer` class hasn't any properties defined regarding with the customer's address. You query fetch this information from the database, but you don't use it. So a **more fast solution** than the above would it be to define this extra properties to the `Customer` class and that's all.

Comment: With the request SQL, there is a property adress but I don't know how to reach it :
http://i.stack.imgur.com/aW19R.png

Comment: Just use dot notation, client.Adresse

Comment: I managed thank you ! Would you have an idea for my second question? thank you again